# require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to install phpUnit on my MAC 10.8 osx.

However everytime I execute the command phpunit on the terminal, I am getting the following error.: 
mkothari-nbook:~ mkothari$ phpunit
PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/php/includes') in /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

I have tried to update the php.ini file with the following paths but none have given me success with the installation:

```
include_path=".:/usr/local/php/pear/"
;include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear"
;include_path = “.:/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit”
```

MY phpunit files are located at this location:

```
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/GlobalState.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/InvalidArgumentHelper.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/PHP.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/String.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/TestSuiteIterator.php
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Type.php`enter code here`
php /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/XML.php
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo vi `which phpunit`

After line 38

define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');

Add this line

ini_set('include_path', '/usr/lib/php:.');

Comment: For me the appropriate directory to add in place of /usr/lib/php was /opt/local/lib/php, since I use MacPorts.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507